# Syntax Error In Python Print Statement

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, syntax-error

I am trying to figure out why I am receiving the following syntax error on my Python print statement in Eclipse:

```
    print(md5_to_hex(md5(message)),' <= "',message.decode('ascii'),'"', sep='')
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Print isn't a function yet, import the future version of print to get it to behave this way.

Answer (score 3):

In python-2.x

```
print(whatever)
```

is roughly* equivalent to

```
print whatever
```

In your case, `whatever` is

```
md5_to_hex(md5(message)),' <= "',message.decode('ascii'),'"', sep=''
```

which is not a valid expression.

* (That's not true if `(whatever)` is a tuple)